# Own dataset works with Sklearn SVM at training but not on prediction

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm new to sklearn and I tried to apply a SVM classifier on my images following an example I found online. I replaced a custom dataset from sklearn with my own by making a similar Bunch dictionary. The fit method works but the prediction does not work(the last line of code `print(clf.predict(dataset_images.data[-5]))` gives the error below)

[image]

Entire code

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.utils import Bunch
import cv2


DATABASE_PATH = "C://Users//Maria//Downloads//ees//CASIA-IrisV2"
csv_file = "generate_csv//generate_csv_correctly_detected.csv"

images_names = pd.read_csv(csv_file)


def getImagesAndLabels():
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    dataset_images = {"data": [], "target": []}
    for index in range(len(df)):
        img_path = DATABASE_PATH + "//" + images_names.iloc[index, 0]
        img = cv2.imread(img_path)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        img = [list(part) for part in img]
        flatten = lambda img: [item for sublist in img for item in sublist]
        img = flatten(img)
        dataset_images["data"].append(img)
        dataset_images["target"].append(np.array(images_names.iloc[index, 1]))
    dataset_images["data"] = np.array(dataset_images["data"])
    dataset_images["target"] = np.array(dataset_images["target"])
    dataset = Bunch(data = dataset_images["data"], target = dataset_images["target"])
    return dataset

dataset_images = getImagesAndLabels()

digits = datasets.load_digits()
print(digits.data[:10])
print(digits.target[:10])
print("urm:")
print(dataset_images.data[:10])
print(dataset_images.target[:10])

clf = svm.SVC()

X, y = dataset_images.data[:-10], dataset_images.target[:-10]

clf.fit(X, y)

print(clf.predict(dataset_images.data[-5]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `predict` call is expecting a 2d array, since that's how you have passed your training data. To perform predict on a single sample, you can change your `predict` call to:

```
clf.predict(dataset_images.data[-5].reshape(1,-1))
```